# The orientation of the mesh is not aligned to the rig. How to fix this issue?

Tags: rigging, armature, import, transform-orientation

I'm new to blender but I have not found a thread with this exact problem.

I imported this file into blender: https://free3d.com/3d-model/manuel-animated-001-dancing-256270.html

but the orientation of the mesh is not aligned to the rig:

[image]

I can change the orientation of the mesh using the "Manual Orientation" on the import box but the armature will rotate perpendicular to the mesh. I can't get them to align.

here's the import setting I inputted:
[image]

I tried a different file (https://free3d.com/3d-model/3d-twilight-model-animated-627891.html) but results were the same.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? @.@